# Searching a specific string in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Simple coder with a simple question possibly.

I have a text box (txtMsg), which when I type something in it (i.e. "I am bored") and press a button (btnSubmit) it shows the text in a list box (lstMsg).

I would like to check whether a particular word ("yes") is being typed by the user when they press the Submit button as a separate part of my code.

The problem I have is the "yes" can be at any point in the textbox, and the user is free to write any word/phrase in there.

My original code was;

```
If txtMsg.Contains(" yes ") Then
lstMsg.Items.Add("Good")
```

Unfortunately, the above code doesn't capture a yes if it is the only thing written (i.e. the user doesn't include a space before and after it) or if it is the last word at the end of a phrase (i.e. not having a space at after the 'yes').

A key problem I have is that searching on "yes" (without spaces) provides a successful outcome according to the code for a word such as "yesterday", even though this is not acceptable for me, the user.

Any tips?

Comment: Do you know how to use regular expressions?

Comment: I'm kind of self-teaching myself on the fly, so I have a lower understanding than you for sure :)

Comment: How about `If Regex.IsMatch(txtMsg, "\byes\b") Then...`?  The `\b` part matches on word boundaries, so matches the whole word "yes", but not "yesterday" etc.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't looking for " yes " so you shouldn't be searching for it with the contains method.  You are looking for "yes".

Instead use txtMsg.toLower.contains("yes") and the if statement will execute regardless of what is before or after "yes".  It also will disregard capitalization (in case "yes" contains capitalized letters).

```
Dim contained as Boolean = False
Dim loc as integer = txtMsg.toLower.indexOf("yes")
If loc >= 0 Then
    If loc > 0 And loc < txtMsg.length - 3 Then
        If Not txtMsg.substring(loc - 1, loc).isAlpha And 
           Not txtMsg.substring(loc + 3, loc + 4).isAlpha Then
            lstMsg.Items.Add("Good")
            contained = true
        End If
    ElseIf loc > 0 Then
        If Not txtMsg.substring(loc - 1, loc).isAlpha Then
            lstMsg.Items.Add("Good")
            contained = true
        End If
    Else
        If Not txtMsg.substring(loc + 3, loc + 4).isAlpha Then
            lstMsg.Items.Add("Good")
            contained = true
        End If
    End If            
ElseIf contained = False
    'your code here 
End If
```

It's a bit of work without regex but this should do it.

Comment: I want two events to occur, based on if "yes" is found or not.  

If yes is found, then do event 1 - If yes is NOT found then do event 2, so in that case I still require the if statement?  

And finally thanks for pointing out but the content of txtmsg is already lowercased from earlier coding in my solution that I haven't mentioned in this post - but thank you for acknowledging and assisting that fact :)

Comment: Just add an else statement, if the if-test returns false, the code in the else statement gets executed instead of the code in the if statement.  I've posted an edit to my code.

Comment: Thanks Luke.

I did try this, but the problem here is a successful IF would occur for the phrase "Yesterday" (as an example) - because of the existence of "yes" in the word.  This particular element has what has been troubling me the most.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay, I've revised my code again.  Your code "lstMsg.Items.Add("Good")" will only execute when "yes" was found, and the character before and after "yes" is not a letter of the alphabet.  This should avoid the problem of words like "Yesterday".

Answer (score 0):

Ok from what I can understand from your question and comments, instead of using a listbox to search for the value and having it conflict with "yes" and "yesterday" I would use an Array.
With that being said, give this a try.
First of all declare this right under the `Public Class Form1`

```
Dim myList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
```

This will allow you to access this Array from wherever on `Form1` or whatever you have named your current form you are working from.
Next add this to your button that it executing the command (I used `Button1`)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If myList.Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower) Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} already exists", TextBox1.Text))
        TextBox1.Clear()
    Else
        myList.Add(TextBox1.Text)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Once you have done all of this, your page should look something like this**

```
Public Class Form1
Dim myList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If myList.Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower) Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} already exists", TextBox1.Text))
        TextBox1.Clear()
    Else
        myList.Add(TextBox1.Text)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```